# A word describing best wishes

Tags: single-word-requests

If I want to share my empathy with someone who has suffered bad luck or heartache, I could be sharing my *condolences* or messages of *commiseration*. Neither of these words imply the actual words used, but we know that something was done to convey sympathy or empathy.

I'm looking for a similar word to describe (but not quote) a message of good luck. Right now, I'm tempted to go with *good-luck message*, but I can hardly believe that's the best term.

Comment: A good luck message.

Comment: 'Bless' carries the meaning but also too many strong connotations.